# Avoiding Replay Attacks on Lightweight Channel

Tags: cryptography, hmac

I'm in the process of building a network of small devices (ARM microcontrollers with something like nRF24L01 connectivity).  The controllers will be receiving commands from a central system over these wireless links, and I'm in the process of designing the protocol.  Confidentiality is a non-goal, but integrity & authenticity are.  Accordingly, we need to validate both the source and avoid replay attacks of the packets.  I'd like to avoid any challenge/response protocols to minimize traffic and battery drain, so what I have in mind is something like this:

- Key and device ID are burned in to device in the firmware.
- A counter is initialized to 0.
- Each command sent to the device contains the device ID, counter++, and the command itself.  Then an HMAC-SHA1 is calculated over all of these fields and attached.
- Upon receiving a command, the device verifies the HMAC-SHA1, device ID **and** ensures that the counter value is strictly larger than the counter stored in NVRAM.  If so, it sets the NVRAM counter to the value in the received packet and carries out the command.
- (Possibly an ack of some sort here.)

Is this protocol similar to anything that exists (I couldn't find anything) or is there anything suitable that already exists?  Am I missing a major flaw?

Comment: How many devices?

Comment: Also, looks fine. Only question is: how are you going to track all the counters?

Comment: In the initial deployment, probably ~10-12, but I don't see a problem with scaling here.

Comment: I don't see any flaws. I think one minor point is missing in your description. The device must also check the device ID. Otherwise, it would execute commands which are intended for other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only suggestion I can give is to always check for acks, and make them include the counter, otherwise an attacker could selectively drop (or delay, but not reorder) packets.

Also, you need to think of a way to keep track of every device counter's value.

Comment: What would you do if an ACK is missing? Send the command again with an increased counter? Then, if the ACK is droped by an attacker the server would resend the command with an increased counter and the device would do execute the command again.

Comment: Why do you think is it necessary to keep track of every device's counter?

Comment: Because otherwise you cannot detect packets dropped by an attacker